# RSS feeds: How to reformat/rewrite/restyle? Using views? e.g. convert youtube text list of videos into thumbnails?

Tags: 7, views, files, feeds

How can a RSS feed be reformatted/rewritten/restyled to be more useful?

For example Youtube RSS feeds from the video uploads of a youtube user appear as a plain text list by default.

Are there drupal module(s) or a solution out there that parses this content to be able to transform it into something more useful? E.g. in the case of youtube, make it show the list as thumbnail stills of the videos uploaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are 2 solutions that would provide the basis for taking an *incoming* RSS feed *into* a Drupal site and manipulating/processing/re-purposing it, USING Views:

http://dev.nodeone.se/en/learn-views-with-nodeone-part-12-building-a-custom-rss-reader-example

**Update:**

http://drupal.org/project/feeds_imagegrabber

Feeds Image Grabber is possibly closer to what I'm looking for regarding rewriting *incoming* RSS feeds.

As for previously mentioned http://drupal.org/project/views_rss
This module is for *outputting* views from the site as an RSS feed - not what I want but useful should I wish parts of my site be available elsewhere via RSS.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Views will be the perfect module choice for you, there are many ways to tweak the output with Views & it has built in Feeds support.  Google about drupal views rss feeds, you'll find a ton of info.  When you install views there is an example rss feed view you can enable and take a look at to see how its done.  As for the thumbnails if your using emfield you should have the option to display thumbnail when tweaking the field output from within the View.

Good luck!

Comment: +1 Thanks @macrocosm. I will look further and I hope to accept your answer later and add specific comments about my case.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find that views can do a lot of very cool stuff. Enjoy! :)

Comment: I think http://drupal.org/project/feeds and http://drupal.org/project/feeds_imagegrabber modules will provide the ability to display the photos from the urls of them provided in the feed from the site that hosts them - see also tutorial http://publicmind.in/blog/tutorial-for-feeds-image-grabber/